# Increment non-primary key fieild within INSERT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, increment

I'm trying to copy rows from old company to the new one.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] ON;

INSERT INTO [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] 
       ([HRCo]
      ,[Code]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Description]
      ,[SafetyYN]
      ,[Notes]
      ,[UniqueAttchID]
      ,[CertPeriod]   
      ,[KeyID]
      ,[PTOTypeYN]
      ,[PRLeaveCode]) 
SELECT '6',
       SomeTable.Code
      ,SomeTable.Type
      ,SomeTable.Description
      ,SomeTable.SafetyYN
      ,SomeTable.Notes
      ,SomeTable.UniqueAttchID
      ,SomeTable.CertPeriod    
      ,[KeyID]      
      ,SomeTable.PTOTypeYN
      ,SomeTable.PRLeaveCode
      FROM [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] 
WHERE HRCo = '11'

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] OFF;
```

What i get as result is an error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.SomeTable' with unique index 'biKeyID'. The duplicate key value is (1377).

Is there a way to use increment for this column? (It's not a primary key column) or maybe there's another way to copy multiple records?

Comment: Do you already have an `IDENTITY` in the table? If not, why not make it an `IDENTITY` column? If you do, why not use a `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: Table has identity, yes. Never used sequence before, would it work in this case?

Comment: Which column (or columns) is the PK? Which column is the identity column? Which column is the source of the collision?

Comment: You can also use row_nulber if it’s a one time thing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: [HRCo], [Code] and [Type] - is PK columns. [KeyID] - identity column. It looks like the problem is with [KeyID].

Answer (score 2):

You said in the comments that primary key is on `([HRCo], [Code], [Type])` and `IDENTITY` is `KeyID`. This information should be in the question. It is important for understanding what is going on.

You are setting the `HRCo` to `6` for your copy, so I assume that this guarantees that new primary keys are unique.

As for the `KeyID`, the `IDENTITY` column will get its (new, incremented) values automatically during `INSERT`, so you should not include this column in the `INSERT` statement. This is what `IDENTITY` does. `IDENTITY` assigns new sequential values to new rows automatically. And you should not `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` here. Let `IDENTITY` do what it does.

```
INSERT INTO [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] 
       ([HRCo]
      ,[Code]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Description]
      ,[SafetyYN]
      ,[Notes]
      ,[UniqueAttchID]
      ,[CertPeriod]   
      --,[KeyID]
      ,[PTOTypeYN]
      ,[PRLeaveCode]) 
SELECT '6',
       SomeTable.Code
      ,SomeTable.Type
      ,SomeTable.Description
      ,SomeTable.SafetyYN
      ,SomeTable.Notes
      ,SomeTable.UniqueAttchID
      ,SomeTable.CertPeriod    
      --,[KeyID]      
      ,SomeTable.PTOTypeYN
      ,SomeTable.PRLeaveCode
FROM [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] 
WHERE HRCo = '11'
```

Note, that I removed the `KeyID` column from both `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] ON;
```

You don't have to set the PK value.
For example, if your PK is KeyID, remove this column from your INSERT.

It would be something like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] ON;

INSERT INTO [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] 
       ([HRCo]
      ,[Code]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Description]
      ,[SafetyYN]
      ,[Notes]
      ,[UniqueAttchID]
      ,[CertPeriod]   
      ,[PTOTypeYN]
      ,[PRLeaveCode]) 
SELECT '6',
       SomeTable.Code
      ,SomeTable.Type
      ,SomeTable.Description
      ,SomeTable.SafetyYN
      ,SomeTable.Notes
      ,SomeTable.UniqueAttchID
      ,SomeTable.CertPeriod     
      ,SomeTable.PTOTypeYN
      ,SomeTable.PRLeaveCode
      FROM [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] 
WHERE HRCo = '11'
```